# Add AntD icon inside AntD table cell

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using AntD in a React App. I want to add an icon inside a table cell but I am getting issues. My code for the particular column is as follows:

```
<Column 
   title="Status" 
   dataIndex="status" 
   key="status"
   render={(status === 'locked') ? <span><Icon type="lock" /> </span> : <span> <Icon type="unlock" /></span>} 
/>
```

The first error I am getting is ***Unexpected use of 'status'*** of which in my data source, status is a string.

The other two errors I am getting are

---

***No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly>): Column', gave the following error.
    Type 'Element' is not assignable to type '(text: any, record: unknown, index: number) => ReactNode'.
      Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(text: any, record: unknown, index: number): ReactNode'.***

---

***Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ColumnProps, context?: any): Column', gave the following error.
    Type 'Element' is not assignable to type '(text: any, record: unknown, index: number) => ReactNode'.ts(2769)***

Can anyone assist with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `render` property accepts a function (and not a value like in your snippet).

Also, a more readable form is to make the condition on the `type`:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Table dataSource={dataSource}>
      <Table.Column
        title="Status"
        dataIndex="status"
        key="status"
        render={status => (
          <Icon type={status === 'locked' ? 'lock' : 'unlock'} />
        )}
      />
    </Table>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit dazzling-dewdney-6tq12]